# On X11, hiding the taskbar icon of a secondary glfw window is not working

Tags: x11, glfw

Windows 10 | Ubuntu [WSL](https://ubuntu.com/wsl)

Using native API I'm trying to hide the taskbar icon of a secondary glfw window but it's not working and icon is still visible. Here is the code:

```cpp
auto display = glfwGetX11Display();
Atom skip_taskbar = XInternAtom(display, "_NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR", True);
Atom wm_state = XInternAtom(display,  "_NET_WM_STATE", True);
auto retval = XChangeProperty(display, glfwGetX11Window(win), wm_state,
        XA_ATOM, 32, PropModeReplace,
        (unsigned char *)&skip_taskbar, 1);
std::cout << "XChangeProperty() reted " << retval << std::endl;

XEvent event;
event.xclient.type=ClientMessage;
event.xclient.serial=0;
event.xclient.send_event=True;
event.xclient.message_type=XInternAtom(display,"_NET_WM_STATE",True);
event.xclient.window=glfwGetX11Window(win);
event.xclient.format=32;
event.xclient.data.l[0]=1; /* add */
event.xclient.data.l[1]=XInternAtom(display,"_NET_WM_STATE_SKIP_TASKBAR",True);
event.xclient.data.l[2]=0;
event.xclient.data.l[3]=0;
event.xclient.data.l[4]=0;
XSendEvent(display,DefaultRootWindow(display),False,SubstructureRedirectMask|SubstructureNotifyMask,&event);
```

Any pointers?